# Price inside items object is not correct

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm just switching from Universal-Analytic to Analytic 4 and I want to track the product detail view by using "view_item" event by using this code. The correct price is 605.

```
gtag("event", "view_item", {
        currency: "JPY",
        value: {{ product_price }},
        items: [
            {
            item_id: "{{ Product.jan }}",
            item_name: "{{ Product.name }}",
            currency: "JPY",
            price: {{ product_price }},
            }
        ]
    });
```

Everything is working fine except the "price" property inside the "items" object. it add 6 zero (000000) to my price

Please check the debug view screenshot for more detail
[image: Value property's value is correct]

[image]

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: It seems that even with the [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events](GA4 example) purchase event I got the same values as you.
However, it's seems that the data are recorded correctly by the GA4 and presented fine inside "E-commerce purchases".